# Pass Value of TextArea to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a Partial View that is Rendered inside of another Partial View that is used as the _layout for all views in the project.  There is a textarea for comments.  I need to get the value of the Textarea to the Action Method in my controller.  There is no ViewModel, so I don't know how to capture the contents.

```
   <header>
        <h4> Application Notes </h4>
        <a href="#" class="icon-print"></a>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Comment", "LoanApplication"))
        {
           @Html.TextArea("Comment")
        @*<textarea cols="100" rows="2" name="Comment" placeholder="Leave Comment ..."></textarea>*@
            <input value="Add Comment" type="submit" />
        }
    </header>
```

The controller code is :

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("Comment")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Comment(string comment)
    {
        var loanApplicationServiceProxy = base.ServiceProvider.LoanApplicationServiceProxy;

        var applicationComment = new LoanApplicationComment
        {

        };
        await loanApplicationServiceProxy.PutLoanApplicationCommentAsync(applicationComment);
        return View();

    }
```

It seems as if it should be something easy, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: Parameters are case-sensitive. Try changing markup to `Html.TextArea("comment")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing value from view to controller in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561325/passing-value-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default model binder is not case sensitive, but you may have a problem with the parameter name matching the action name.

Comment: is "LoanApplication" the name of your controller?

Comment: Try removing `[Route("Comment")]` from the action method

Comment: The name of the controller is "LoanApplication"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
string comment
```

To

```
string Comment
```

One other thing to try is to receive a `FormCollection` instead.

Comment: The model binder is not case sensitive.